# Rest Web service Implementation with ZEND

Tags: zend-framework, rest, restful-authentication

I need to develop a REST Web Service using ZEND Framework. I am new to this area. I would like to know how can I authenticate user's requests to my web service. Assume I am giving a token to all the people who use my web service. I can ask them to pass the token on every request. But Please suggest me if there and standard / better way to implement authentication for REST web service.

Thank you.
Prasad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually include the token in the http header with each request then on the server parse the header and validate the token.

```
X-Authorization-Token: <some hash value>
```

It's also completely acceptable to do as you are suggesting and require the user to send the token as part of the GET/POST/PUT/DELETE request as you would with a standard page. I have seen others put the value in a COOKIE as well.

Comment: Thank you friend for your reply